# ssh does not work when called from systemd

Tags: linux, ssh, systemd

I am trying to write a script to rsync a folder on my laptop to my NAS. The script runs fine when called from the commandline. I've tried setting up the script to run automatically with systemd. However, there is a problem with the ssh login. While it works fine when the script is run from the commandline, I get a permission denied error.

Here is what I've tried so far to narrow down the problem:

The script `/home/tikey/scripts/nas_sync_photos_to_nas.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
ssh tikey@192.168.17.200 -v -i /home/tikey/.ssh/id_rsa ls -la rsync_laptop
```

To run the script with systemd, I've put the file `sync-photos-to-nas.service` in `~/.config/systemd/user/`:

```
[Unit]
Description=sync Bilder to nas
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/tikey/scripts/nas_sync_photos_to_nas.sh
```

Running the script from the commandline works fine. Unfortunately, running the script with systemd does not work. I've run the systemd service with `systemctl --user start sync-photos-to-nas.service`. Then, using `journalctl --user-unit sync-photos-to-nas`, I get:

```
...
debug1: Host '192.168.17.200' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/tikey/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/tikey/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
sync-photos-to-nas.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
sync-photos-to-nas.service: Unit entered failed state.
sync-photos-to-nas.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

The log says that your private key is encrypted and the client can't use it before you will enter a passphrase. Either use unencrypted key or use again some dirty workaround using `sshpass`.

Comment: Forgot about this. The key is automatically unlocked when I log in but apparently not for systemd.

Comment: Because it's a different user who has the key/keyring, so it's not unlocked as systemd has no interactive session running

Answer (score 1):

`debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address`

The log says that your private key is encrypted and the client can't use it before you will enter a passphrase. And as you say in your comment:

> The key is automatically unlocked when I log in but apparently not for systemd

To ensure this is done, you need to execute the script as if you logged in with your login name.

```
[Unit]
Description=sync Bilder to nas

[Service]
User=<YOUR USER NAME>
WorkingDirectory=/home/<YOUR USER NAME>
ExecStart=bash -l -c "/home/tikey/scripts/nas_sync_photos_to_nas.sh"
```

from `man bash`:

```
-c string        If  the  -c  option  is  present, then commands are read from
                 string.  If there are arguments after the  string,  they  are
                 assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

-l               Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell (see
                 INVOCATION below).
```

from `man systemd.exec`:

```
User=, Group=    Set the UNIX user or group that the processes are executed as,
                 respectively. Takes a single user or group name, or a numeric 
                 ID as argument. etc...
```

Comment: I still got the `can't open /dev/tty` error with this setup.

Comment: this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

According to `man ssh`, the order of your arguments is wrong in your SSH call. You have this:

```
ssh tikey@192.168.17.200 -v -i /home/tikey/.ssh/id_rsa ls -la rsync_laptop
```

But in the "Synopsis" of `man ssh`, it shows that that all the options must come before "user@host", so try this:

```
 ssh -v -i /home/tikey/.ssh/id_rsa tikey@192.168.17.200 ls -la rsync_laptop
```

The other details of your systemd configuration look reasonable.

Comment: In practice this doesn't actually matter, as long as the command to be run comes at the end. Try this: `ssh myhost -v`, which will turn on the -v argument even after the host declaration.

Comment: @JamiesonBecker it might not matter now, but if you aren't following the documented way to use SSH, then expect no guarantee of future support of  undocumented behaviors.

Comment: .. but it's not an answer. Or, at least not an answer to the question OP was asking. :)